# How to get all dimension values in MetricDataResults in CloudWatch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a search expression that looks like this:

```
stats = cloudwatch.get_metric_data(

        MetricDataQueries=[
            {
            "Id":'m1',
            'Expression': "SEARCH('{ABC/HEARTBEAT,Client_Email, Clinic_Id, NodeName} MetricName=\"PING_PONG\" Clinic_Id = 7667', 'Average', 864000)",
            'ReturnData': True,
        },

        ],
        StartTime=Util.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=2),
        EndTime=Util.utcnow(),
    )
```

It returns:

```
{
    "Messages": [],
    "ResponseMetadata": {
        "RetryAttempts": 0,
        "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
        "RequestId": "2f33cc09-61ff-40b0-9d28-72c4d949b2f0",
        "HTTPHeaders": {
            "x-amzn-requestid": "2f33cc09-61ff-40b0-9d28-72c4d949b2f0",
            "date": "Fri, 06 Dec 2019 22:47:25 GMT",
            "content-length": "928",
            "content-type": "text/xml"
        }
    },
    "MetricDataResults": [
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2019-12-06 20:47:00+00:00"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                1
            ],
            "Id": "m1",
            "Label": "simran+test2@abc.com"
        },
        {
            "Timestamps": [
                "2019-12-06 20:47:00+00:00"
            ],
            "StatusCode": "Complete",
            "Values": [
                1
            ],
            "Id": "m1",
            "Label": "simran+test4@abc.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get value of `Client_Email`, `NodeName` for the metrics that have Clinic_Id = 7667

Currently, I get Client_Email as Label (Not sure why) but I need both `Client_Email` and `NodeName`

Update:

u'MetricDataResults looks like this for me:

```
u'MetricDataResults': [{u'Timestamps': [], u'StatusCode': 'Complete', u'Values': [], u'Id': 'm1', u'Label': 'abc'}, {u'Timestamps': [], u'StatusCode': 'Complete', u'Values': [], u'Id': 'm1', u'Label': 'abc2'}]
```

Why do I have empty array in Timestamps and Values?

Comment: What do you mean by "get values of all dimensions for each of the records"?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Please check the update

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  Please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label is the only place in the response where this value could be.
I suspect you only have 1 distinct value for `NodeName` and that is why the label contains only the `Client_Email`. If you had more combinations of emails and node, they would show in the label, separated by space.

If you're not interested in the values of the metrics, but only in the values of dimensions, you could use `list-metrics` API, like this for example:

```
response = cloudwatch.list_metrics(
    Namespace='ABC/HEARTBEAT',
    MetricName='PING_PONG',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'Clinic_Id',
            'Value': '7667'
        },
    ],
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I lookedup list_metrics.list_metrics does not seem to have Starttime and EndTime. I need StartTime and EndTime to be able to check for it in last few hours. Do we have something better here?

Comment: Also, Is there a way I can determine order of Labels - As in the order in which values of dimensions show up under Labels/

Comment: Maybe the best thing for you would be to use both. First do `list-metrics`, this will give you all metrics that had data published in the last 2 weeks. Then for each metric do GetMetricData to see which metrics had data in the last few hours. How are these metrics published? Perfect feature for you would be ContributorInsights, that that may require you to change the way metrics are published: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-cloudwatch-now-includes-contributor-insights-preview/

Comment: I am writing to SQS first, which triggers a lambda function. When the lambda gets triggered, it writes to cloudwatch using put_metric_data

Comment: You would need to use Embedded Metrics Format instead of PutMetricData to be able to use Contributor Insights. Python and NodeJs are supported with clients: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Embedded_Metric_Format_Libraries.html

Comment: I checked the labels bit. It seems to be working fine to get by for now. Quick question though: Can you check the update in question please?